# Can someone explain what this Ruby code does?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading an introduction to algorithm complexity text and the author has examples in several different languages, which I have been able to follow along. Then at the crucial moment he hits me this Ruby code which is Greek to me. Can someone explain what this code does?

```
b = []
n.times do
    m = a[ 0 ]
    mi = 0
    a.each_with_index do |element, i|
        if element < m
            m = element
            mi = i
        end
    end
    a.delete_at( mi )
    b << m
end
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-translation service. Please close/delete your question and find a more appropriate place to ask it.

Comment: "Hovercraft Full Of Eels I don't agree with you. His question could be asked in different way, for example how to implement this Ruby solution in Java. Anyway this question is completely OK for me, there is no need for downvoting...He is a programmer and he doesn't know how algorithm works, so he asks for help on programmers page. There is no more appropriate page to ask this question.

Comment: I just think this is Too Localized. I do think it can be improved into a better question though.

Comment: @Marek: please see: [close-reason-for-translate-my-code-questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175705/). And you're right, there is no "more approprate" place on stackoverflow for translate this code type questions. There isn't any place on stackoverflow for this.

Comment: See the 2nd answer there. I can only agree that this was too localized, but anyway as we can all see it was possible to help him and probably he is happy now. Thanks to Doorknob :)

Comment: Ok I realized my error and should have framed it as a "what does this do" question. Though possibly that's Too Localized as well

Comment: For me it just means that after you will find help (you already did) some people will flag it as too localized and it will disappear from here. And this is completely perfect solution

Comment: @svenoaks You can still edit your question, and if you improve it, it may be reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b = [] # b is a new array
n.times do # do this n times
    m = a[ 0 ] # m is the first element of a
    mi = 0 # mi (the index of m) is 0
    a.each_with_index do |element, i| # loop through a, with the index
        if element < m # if the element is less than m
            m = element # set m to the element
            mi = i # set mi to the element's index
        end
    end
    a.delete_at( mi ) # delete the element at index mi (which is m)
    b << m # append m to b
end
```

So basically, all the code from `m = a[ 0 ]` to `b << m` just finds the smallest element in `a`, and moves it to `b`. That happens `n` times.

Therefore, what this does is move the `n` smallest elements from `a` to `b`.

Comment: 1+ for explaining the code and not translating it as requested.

Comment: That's the right answer :)

Comment: also note, this is not considered good ruby code... the variables could be named much better, and it could be broken down into smaller methods with intention revealing names.